# What is the license on Magento CE User Guide

Tags: licensing

Is the Magento Community Edition user Guide open source? I mean can I have a copy professionally printed (yes, all ~800 pages). If someone already publishes a print version, that would be great too.

Answer (score 5):

At the bottom of page ii of the Magento Community Edition User Guide, Version 1.9.1 it says:
"Copyright © 2014 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved."

"All rights reserved" is a reference to the copyright law meaning the copyright holder holds all rights gained from the copyright law.

I'm not a (copyright) law expert, especially not for the US, but in a general sense, copyright is an exclusive right that protects the exclusive rights for the creator which usually include the use and distribution.

This might be the reason why there is noone offering printed copies of it but I'm pretty sure you are allowed to print it at a local printer and get it bound.

Answer (score 2):

Magento Community Edition User Guide is readily available online.

You can download and print it for your own reference.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/user-guide-download

Comment: Thank you. I have already downloaded a copy and am finding it awkward to "flip" through the pages on the screen. At 800 pages it makes sense to purchase a print copy or at least to go to a local printer and get it bound. Can you refer me to documentation that allows me to do this?